# How to create POJO class with different structure JSON Object

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonschema2pojo

Here is my json schema

```
[
 {
  "title": "Taman Lansia",
  "alamat": "Jl. Cisangkuy, Citarum, Bandung Wetan, Kota Bandung, Jawa Barat 40123",
  "image": "Link image",
  "status": 1
 },
 {
  "title": "Fasilitas Taman_Lansia",
  "fasilitas": [
    {
     "namaFasilitas": "Area Piknik",
     "imageFasilitas": "Link Image"
    },
    {
     "namaFasilitas": "Jalur Jogging",
     "imageFasilitas": "Link Image"
    }
   ],
   "status": 2
 }
]
```

How to resolve this, because i'm just trying in http://jsonschema2pojo.org and then no result or no response.
Thank you

Comment: thats no real json schema as you can see on your linked website they want s.t like {
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "bar": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "baz": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you POJO obviously has to have every possible attribute you have in your schema and then just have the other values not set as null...

So

```
public class MyObject {
    private String title;
    private List<OtherObject> fasilitas;
...

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and i really appreciated your problem solving